# 401 Unauthorized error using streamR

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, roauth

I am trying to connect to twitter's streaming API using streamR and the required ROAuth package.  I follow the exact procedure from the documentation [here](https://github.com/pablobarbera/streamR), but when I have finished all the steps with no errors I receive a 401 Unauthorized error when calling`filterStream` or `sampleStream`.

Here are the steps that appear to work fine:

```
library(ROAuth)
library(streamR)

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "--redacted--"
consumerSecret <- "--redacted--"

my_oauth <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumerKey, 
                             consumerSecret = consumerSecret, 
                             requestURL = requestURL, 
                             accessURL = accessURL, 
                             authURL = authURL)

my_oauth$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

When I run the final line a browser window is opened which asks me to authorize the app to use my twitter account.  When I click to authorize a PIN appears which I am copy/pasting into Rstudio after the prompt reading "When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:"

After running the above lines, I am sending a call like this to `filterStream`:
    `filterStream(file.name = "test_tweets.json", track = c("sat"), timeout = 120, oauth = my_oauth)`

The generated file test_tweets.json reads: `Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason: Unauthorized`

To resolve the problem I have tried creating a new twitter app, updating R and all packages.  None of these actions produced any differing results.  Additionally, I tried the same credentials with the `twitteR` package, which worked fine, but unfortunately I need to connect to the streaming api which is not available through the `twitteR` package. Any tips greatly appreciated!

Note this question is related to, but different from, [this unanswered question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088690/streamr-userstream-error-401-unauthorized)

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, creating a new twitter account fixed this problem; but only after I had associated my phone with the account AND checked all the boxes in the mobile notifications section.  Bizarre, but it worked.  After I got it working I was able to uncheck the notifications and it still worked.

You, reader, fellow mysterious-error-receiver, are not alone: http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate your customerKey and customerSecret when you change your twitter permissions from Read - Write to Read-Write and Direct Messages.